# How to output /p:Platform="Any CPU" as quoted from shake cmd?

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I'm using [`cmd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.10.7/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:cmd) from Shake and having trouble forming the following command line ...

```
msbuild a.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

When I try escaping the double quote, the escaping and string quoting flows too far and get this error ...

```
Development.Shake.cmd, system command failed
Command: msbuild a.sln /p:Configuration=Debug "/p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""
Exit code: 1
```

I've tried 3 ways ...

```
cmd "msbuild a.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""
cmd "msbuild a.sln /p:Configuration=Debug" ["/p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""]
cmd "msbuild" ["a.sln", "/p:Configuration=Debug", "/p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""]
```

I am running this on Windows.

Comment: I think you should be able to pass `"/p:Platform=Any CPU"` instead, and `msbuild` should work equivalently. I suspect to pass exactly that string to `msbuild` you need to `Shell` to the first option, but I'll check properly later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a little C program (which I named `msbuild`) to test:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("{%s}\n", GetCommandLine());
    return 0;
}
```

Using that I tested your variants:

```
cmd "msbuild a.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""
{"msbuild" "a.sln" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:Platform=\"Any" "CPU\""}
cmd "msbuild a.sln /p:Configuration=Debug" ["/p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""]
{"msbuild" "a.sln" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""}
cmd "msbuild" ["a.sln", "/p:Configuration=Debug", "/p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""]
{"msbuild" "a.sln" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""}
```

The one that fixes this is to use the `Shell` command, to tell Shake to avoid doing any of its own escaping:

```
cmd Shell "msbuild a.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""
{msbuild  a.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"}
```

However, assuming the real `msbuild` is like the other Visual Studio tools (e.g. `fsc`, `csc`, `cl`), you can probably use the equivalent (and perhaps preferred) variant of:

```
msbuild a.sln /p:Configuration=Debug "/p:Platform=Any CPU"
```

Which you can express with Shake as:

```
cmd "msbuild a.sln /p:Configuration=Debug" ["/p:Platform=Any CPU"]
```